# SQL check for 2 equal and sequential values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named sapinteraction which has the following structure:

```
interactionId: String
interactionObject: String
action: String
interactionDate : DateTime
```

Right now i have query to check the `last 2 records` of each interactionObject for a specified `action`.

```
SELECT max(subTab.interactionDate) AS Maxdate, ssubTab.ts AS MaxMaxDate, subTab.interactionObject,  subTab.action As PrevLastAction , ssubTab.action AS LastAction
FROM sapinteraction  subTab
JOIN(
    SELECT max(subsubTab.interactionDate) ts, subsubTab.interactionObject, subsubTab.action
    FROM sapinteraction  subsubTab
    GROUP BY subsubTab.interactionObject,subsubTab.action
    ) ssubTab ON ssubTab.interactionObject = subTab.interactionObject AND ssubTab.ts > subTab.interactionDate
WHERE  (subTab.s_resultstatus_in <> 1) AND (subTab.interactionDate > '2013-01-01') AND subTab.action = 'DELETE' AND ssubTab.action = 'DELETE'
GROUP BY subTab.interactionObject,subTab.action , ssubTab.action
```

**Question:**
I wish to change the query so that `retrieve any interactionObject` which has the action `'Delete' (example) in twice in a row` (according to the datetime). Any idea how to modify my query to achieve this?

As Requested some data (orded by interactionObject, interactionDate)

```
interactionId   |  interactionObject   |   action             |    interactionDate 
___________________________________________________________________________________________
1093            | Object1              | ADD                  | 2014 - 07 -01
1088            | Object1              | DELETE               | 2014 - 06 -20
1075            | Object1              | ADD                  | 2014 - 05 -13
1066            | Object1              | DELETE               | 2014 - 04 -07
1035            | Object1              | ADD                  | 2014 - 03 -15

1901            | Object2              | ADD                  | 2014 - 07 -01
1807            | Object2              | DELETE               | 2014 - 06 -05
1707            | Object2              | DELETE               | 2014 - 05 -12
1613            | Object2              | ADD                  | 2014 - 04 -13
1500            | Object2              | ADD                  | 2014 - 03 -21

1000            | Object3              | ADD                  | 2014 - 07 -22
1000            | Object3              | DELETE               | 2014 - 06 -19
1000            | Object3              | ADD                  | 2014 - 05 -16
1000            | Object3              | DELETE               | 2014 - 04 -13
1000            | Object3              | DELETE               | 2014 - 03 -10


In the case standing above: i would like to retrieve Object2 & Object3
```

Comment: will you provide some data here and expected result

Comment: Added some proviosal data.

Comment: in oracle, this would be a LAG function

Comment: I'm a little confused - you talk about wanting to check the "last 2 records" but in your sample data, although both objects 2 and 3 have two `DELETE`s in a row, those don't appear to be the "last 2 records" for their respective objects. Do you just want to find any objects where two interactions in a row are `DELETE`?

Comment: I'm sorry , my question is not clear. I'll adjust it. My current query checks the last 2 interaction. Like you said: I want to find any objects with interactions in a row where the action is 'DELETE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we just want to find objects that have had two `DELETE` interactions in a row, we can do this as:

```
;With Numbered as (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY interactionObject
       ORDER BY interactionDate) as rn
    FROM sapinteraction
)
SELECT distinct n1.interactionObject
FROM
     Numbered n1
        inner join
     Numbered n2
        on
            n1.interactionObject = n2.interactionObject and
            n1.rn = n2.rn - 1
WHERE
   n1.action = 'DELETE' and
   n2.action = 'DELETE'
```

Which is hopefully straightforward to read.

[`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx), [`WITH` Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175972.aspx) for reference. And I've used `DISTINCT` on the presumption that even if a particular object has had *multiple* occurrences of two `DELETE`s in a row, you only want it to appear in the results once.

This can also easily be changed to find pairs of *any* actions that happen twice in a row by changing the where clause to `n1.action = n2.action`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution Worked brilliantly! And its also quite more readable then my solution. thank you also for the reference. It offered me quite a nice read.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+ the LAG() function would allow you to do this, but in SQL 2008 I think using an outer apply to get the next row would work. It might perform better if backed by an index on interactiondate like`create index idx_date on sapinteraction(interactiondate)`.

```
select * 
from sapinteraction t1
outer apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from sapinteraction t2 
    where T1.interactionObject = t2.interactionObject
    and t1.interactionDate < t2.interactionDate 
    order by interactionDate
    ) oa
where t1.action = 'DELETE' and oa.action = 'DELETE'
```

Using a correlated subquery should work too.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give it a shot! Never used `outer apply`before. Didn't even know it existed.

Comment: @N55PEC While it should work it will most likely perform a lot worse than the accepted answer (but that hadn't been posted when I started on mine) unless it's backed by an index like `create index ix2 on sapinteraction(interactiondate)` in which case it might perform better.

Comment: It indeed performs somewhat slower then the other query, but it outputs the same results. therefor the +1. Thank you for your solution and pointing me to the existance of `outer apply`

Comment: @N55PEC You might want to try it after adding the index, the query plan suggests it might be a lot faster, but it could be wrong :)

Comment: tried it and i noticed a great performance increase. Performance-wise its now the equal of the first query.

Comment: @N55PEC Good to know, the execution plans suggested the outer apply query should have a 28% cost compared to 72% cost for the row_number query.